# How to sum column values of a select query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to display the "total of all values" in the column `NetPrice` to a textbox which is in the form footer if a user chooses items in the two combo boxes. This should be true for only the displayed records.
I don't know how to go about this and hope someone has done this before. I would really appreciate some help.

```
Private Sub comboPeriod_AfterUpdate()
Dim strSQL As String

If Me.comboPeriod.Value = "Q1" And Len(Me.comboPostCode.Value & vbNullString) <> 0  Then
   strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qrySpending WHERE (Month(orderDate) = 4 OR Month(orderDate) = 5 OR 
   Month(orderDate) = 6) AND (PostCode = '" & Me.comboPostCode.Value & "') ORDER BY Description ASC"

   Me.frmDatasheet.Form.RecordSource = strSQL
   Me.frmMain.Form.Requery

   Me.txtNetPrice.Value = DSum(Nz("NetPrice", 0), "strSQL")
Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You may get more of a response if you add the SQL tag to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain aggregate functions cannot reference SQL statement, only table and query objects. Do aggregate calc in a grouping query which can be the SQL statement in your code. However, SQL statement is not really needed for this. Simply use filter criteria in DSum() in textbox or VBA.

`DSum("NetPrice", "qrySpending", "Month(orderDate) = 4 OR Month(orderDate) = 5 OR Month(orderDate) = 6) AND (PostCode = '" & Me.comboPostCode & "'")`